# How to load a CSS file inside a template through source() that includes a path to a font

Tags: css, templates, drupal, twig

I am trying to load a css file inside a template which has a path to a font.
Now the file loads correctly, though the relative path inside the CSS file is wrong from template point of view. What can I do?
The CSS file is being generated through webpack with a relative path.

```
<style type="text/css">
  {{ source(directory ~ '/dist/critical.css') }}
</style>

----

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Calibri'),
     url('../fonts/calibri.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: you have a typo in `/..fonts/calibri.woff2` ... i think this must be `../fonts/calibri.woff2`

Comment: Of course you are right, that's a bug I built in while copying to stackoverflow